# CSS Animation Slide Up Child element over the parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, angular

I am trying to achieve slide up animation where the row can have 4/2/1 columns. Each column has an image, title and description. All of which can be of variable sizes and hence I am using flex to keep the size of each column equal. The title is displayed completely however only the first line of description is shown and rest is hidden. (I cannot figure out a way to align the descriptions correctly)

When you hover over a column, I want the title and description to slide up over the image showing the entire description. If the description is even longer, just hide the rest. The main requirement is that the height of the column should not change on hovering.

Here is the fiddle that I created: https://jsfiddle.net/hbnkfmcr/3/

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.label {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.label p {
  line-height: 14px;
  max-height: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col:hover p {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.hondahookup.com/images/100x100.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        <h4>Title
                    </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://www.hondahookup.com/images/100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <h4>Long Title Here
                    </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://www.hondahookup.com/images/100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <h4>Title
                    </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://www.hondahookup.com/images/100x100.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <h4>Title
                    </h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am open to using JavaScript as long as it is Angular 2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your label text to another div with specified height:

```
.label-text{
  height:50px
}

<div class="label">
    <div class=label-text><h4>Title</h1></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hbnkfmcr/7/

Comment: Thanks for the response. But like I mentioned the title can be variable length too so I cannot set the height on label.

Answer (score 0):

A css only solution making minimal changes to what you currently have (adding these declarations to the styling file):

```
.col:hover .image {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col:hover .label, .col:hover .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.col:hover p {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

In action:

https://jsfiddle.net/hbnkfmcr/8/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Though this is close, it is not exactly what I want. The slide up animation isn't there. And I don't want the text to take up the entire height. Thanks again.